# « Les médecins veulent resserrer la loi » : le procès du verbe ?

Tags: usage, verbes, passif, figure-de-style, formulation

Un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sante/201902/11/01-5214356-armes-a-feu-des-medecins-veulent-resserrer-la-loi.php) s'intitule « Armes à feu: des médecins veulent resserrer la loi »<sup>1</sup>. Le sens qui semble convenir au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/resserrer) est celui de de *borner par des limites étroites* et [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/resserrer/68726?q=resserrer#67973) présente le sens de *[rendre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rendre) quelque chose plus rigoureux, plus sévère* ; c'est *rendre* dans le sens de *faire devenir*. On connaît par ailleurs des emplois pronominaux, voire passifs pour d'autres acceptions du verbe. Par ailleurs on sait que c'est techniquement le législateur ou le pouvoir législatif qui en fait « resserre » la loi (en changeant son contenu, ses normes etc.).

---

- Considérant les nuances des emplois et la sémantique du verbe
  *resserrer* ainsi que le rôle du législateur, pourquoi trouve-t-on également juste ou non de dire en contexte que :

  > 1.Les médecins veulent resserrer la loi.
  >  2.Les médecins veulent voir
  >   la loi resserrée/être resserrée.
  >  3.Les médecins veulent faire
  >   resserrer la loi.
  >  4.Les médecins veulent rendre plus sévère la
  >   loi.
  >  5.Les médecins veulent que la loi soit plus sévère.
- L'utilisation du verbe *resserrer* dans la première phrase (titre de
  l'article) est-elle vraiment typique, cohérente : y a-t-il une
  synecdoque, une métonymie, une ellipse ou s'agit-il uniquement d'une extension de sens ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> En passant il n'existe au Canada aucun droit (et surtout pas constitutionnel) de posséder une arme à feu autre que celui aménagé par la loi. La possession [nécessite](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/C-46/page-19.html#h-40) une autorisation (art. 91 du *Code criminel*) accordée dans un [permis](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/F-11.6/TexteComplet.html) délivré (art. 4 *Loi sur les armes à feu*) à certaines conditions (art. 5  de la même loi) prescrites par la loi. Toute autre affirmation serait fausse.</sub>

Comment: Any effing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "vouloir + infinitive" when one lacks the power to personally take the desired action seems, to me, somewhat presumptuous, which is probably why I think I would have preferred either:

> 2.Les médecins veulent voir la loi resserrée or
>
> 5.Les médecins veulent que la loi soit [resserrée]/plus sévère

as the article's title.

Although the addition of "faire" in "3. Les médecins veulent faire resserrer la loi" seems to render that option more doable/less presumptuous than the original title (Option 1) or even Option 4 (with its use of "rendre"), I still think either Options 2 or 5 capture best the doable/unpresumptuous goal/notion of "... **réclamer** un meilleur contrôle des armes à feu au Canada ..." found in the article's body.

---

Please note that, in my opinion, the presumptuousness that I detect in the original title would disappear (alas, along with its "idiomaticness") if "vouloir + [a not doable/not permitted] infinitive" could be changed to "vouloir + **the noun form** of that same undoable infinitive," i.e.,

> 1. Les médecins veulent le resserrage de la loi.

---

cf: [This article's title](https://www.lavoixacadienne.com/index.php/actualites/1138-barack-obama-veut-resserrer-le-controle-des-armes-aux-etats-unis) using "vouloir + resserrer" (similarly, along with "réclamait" in the article's body) where President Obama had actually already announced his intention to, by Executive Order, accomplish the desired "resserrage." (so the President, unlike the Doctors, had the power and was about to use it, making me tempted to wonder why the title used "vouloir" instead of "aller": "Barack Obama **va** resserrer le contrôle des armes aux États-Unis."

Comment: Maybe a hint as to why it possibly makes no actual difference (but for connotations re: other A.) with this sort of construction is because with _vouloir_ and the infinitive the latter wouldn't need to indicate an actual [_procès_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s_(linguistique)) as it's always about a desired result, although this is way beyond me re:linguistics. But I find _réclamer un meilleur contrôle_ to be more typical/"true" than all the variations I provided. Finally, about the lavoixcadienne article, maybe _vouloir_ was used because of some possible check/balance re:Congress?

Comment: You're welcome btw. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Tous les exemples que vous citez dans votre 1er point signifient à peu près la même chose, et pourraient être utilisés comme titre de l'article.

Ici ils ont employé la phrase.

> Les médecins veulent resserrer la loi

Principalement pour renforcer l'implication des médecins à vouloir que cette loi soit plus sévère. Je suppose pour susciter l'empathie du lecteur pour les médecins, dans cet article.